# xamarin : Cannot recognize a customized Mainpage.xaml (myMainPage.xaml) with different namespace "AwesomeApp.Pages"

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, f#

I defined a customized `MainPage.xaml(myMainPage.xaml)` in a new folder named `Pages` to the root of the AwesomeApp project. However, it can't be recognized by the `App.xaml.fs`. Only the `MainPage.xaml`(the contentPage was generated by visual Studio for mac) can be recognized. Please comment how to fix the problem. Thank you.

App.xaml.fs

```
namespace AwesomeApp

open Xamarin.Forms
open AwesomeApp.Pages

type App() =
    inherit Application(MainPage = myMainPage())
```

myMainPage.xaml.fs

```
namespace AwesomeApp.Pages

open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

type myMainPage() =
    inherit ContentPage()
    let _ = base.LoadFromXaml(typeof<myMainPage>)
```

## **UPDATE**

It seems it is a bug in visual studio for Mac. When the project was generated with C#, the namespace "Pages" can be recognized successfully.

Comment: Did you add the .fs files to the .fsproj ?

Comment: I didn't. It is not required for the project in c#. is it a requirement for the project in f#?

Comment: yes, for F# all files need to be listed (in order of usage!) in the proj file.

Comment: found the contents already exist in the .fsproj <EmbeddedResource Include="Pages\MainPage.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Pages\MainPage.xaml.fs">
      <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>

Comment: Is MainPage.xaml.fs above App.xaml.fs?

Comment: Fixed. After moving Pages\MainPage.xml above App.xaml.fs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the F# compiler file order matters. Ensure that the `Compile` entry for `App.xaml.fs` is after/below `MyMainPage.xaml.fs` in the `.fsproj` project file.